# Using contains method in HashSet to compare Maps in java

Tags: java

I am implementing several solvers (BFS and A*) for n-puzzle. I am using HashSet for maintaining the closed list as the contains method has O(1) time.

My HashSet is a set of HashMaps (integer to integer), so I want to see if the HashSet contains the specified map. If HashSet's name is `set` and the HashMap's name is `map`, is it enough to write:

```
set.contains(map);
```

to check if both the keys and the values of `map` match with any of the keys and values of maps in the set?

If not, what way could be the fastest to check the values of `map` against a list of maps?

I have also tried creating a list of maps and then use equals method of map to compare each map in the list but it seems too slow as the size of closed list increases.

Comment: Why didn’t you just run it and find out for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `contains()` to see if an object like your given `Map` object is inside the `Set` you have. The `contains()` method will use the `equals()` method to compare the objects, and the `equals()` method of `HashMap` is [defined as follow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns `true` if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps `m1` and `m2` represent the same mappings if `m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())`. This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the `Map` interface.

See the following example source code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Map<Integer, Integer>> sets = new HashSet<Map<Integer, Integer>>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        m1.put(1, 4);
        m1.put(2, 3);
        sets.add(m1);
        Map<Integer, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        m2.put(1, 4);
        m2.put(6, 7);
        sets.add(m2);
        System.out.println(sets);

        Map<Integer, Integer> m3 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        System.out.println(m3+" | "+sets.contains(m3));
        m3.put(6, 7);
        System.out.println(m3+" | "+sets.contains(m3));
        m3.put(1, 4);
        System.out.println(m3+" | "+sets.contains(m3));
    }
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
[{1=4, 2=3}, {1=4, 6=7}]
{} | false
{6=7} | false
{1=4, 6=7} | true
```

You see at the end the `contains()` method will return `true` as it matches an existing `Map` object inside your `Set`.

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't really `O(1)` any more, it's `O(` sum of the sizes of all the maps in that hash bucket `)` - so will be slow, potentially very slow.